# Mutating local properties in Vue / Nuxt (typescript)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'd like to have a property `showLogo` that can be set to `false` when I call the method `hideLogo()`

```
import Component from 'nuxt-class-component'
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Logo from '~/components/Logo.vue'

@Component({
  components: {
    Logo
  }
})

export default class extends Vue {
  @Prop({ default: true })
  showLogo: boolean

  hideLogo(): void {
    this.showLogo = false
  }
}
```

This produces the warning: 
`[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "showLogo"`

What's the correct way to perform this task?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: @yuriy636 I might be misinterpreting the documentation, but it sounds like the issue presents itself when you have child components referencing and mutating their parent component properties, going against the downward flow of state changes.  My component doesn't have any children and is modifying its own property `showLogo` with its own method `hideLogo()` -- no other components reference `showLogo`, so the data flow is self-contained.

Comment: Isn't `showLogo` a prop which your component receives from a parent? Or even if it isn't passed, it is still a prop and Vue still triggers the warning.

Comment: @yuriy636 `showLogo` is triggered from an event defined within the same component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error output gives you a good hint. You should never directly mutate props from inside the component. Props are meant to be only accessible by parent components in a template, like so:

```
<template>
  <your-component :show-logo="true">
<template>
```

If you want to have a value that is mutable from inside the component, do as your error tells you: **"Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value."**

Since you are using typescript, your data should look like so:

```
export default class extends Vue {
  showLogo: boolean = true

  hideLogo(): void {
    this.showLogo = false
  }
}
```